# Does it fails extra invokes if reaches Max concurrent invocations in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning to trigger a background function for one of my collections. I would use onWrite of that collection and perform some job.

From the below link -

> The maximum concurrent invocations of a single function
> For example: if handling each event takes 100 seconds, the invocation rate will be limited to 30 per second on average

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#additional_quotas_for_background_functions

So I want to know if I trigger a background function for each write and let say it crosses the max invocation in a second, does it gonna be fail the extra requests? Or queued up and take extra requests in the next batch?

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look into the [following](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees):

> - **It can take up to 10 seconds for a function to respond** to changes in Cloud Firestore.
> - **Ordering is not guaranteed**. Rapid changes can trigger function invocations in an unexpected order.
> - **Events are delivered at least once**, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics, and write idempotent functions.

Next, what will happen when [your background function reaches any quota limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#when_you_reach_a_quota_limit)?

> When a function consumes all of an allocated resource, the resource becomes unavailable until the quota is refreshed or increased. This may mean that your function and all other functions in the same project will not work until then. A function returns an HTTP 500 error code when one of the resources is over quota and the function cannot execute.

Thus, although every event is delivered (queued) at least once, once your function reaches the quota limit, subsequent invocations will return a server side error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I performed an experiment:

1. Have an .onCreate firebase function that is triggered when a document is added in a collection.
2. Have an external function create hundreds/thousands of documents per second in that collection.

The results were that out of 12668 total documents written within about 3 seconds, 4 were left unattended to and were not handled by the firebase function. The large majority were handled within the first second, while the last few hundred documents got slower and slower to trigger the firebase function, until the last 4 failed to trigger.

It would be interesting to see an actual bell-curve graph and scientific-ish article about how firebase/GCP handles this much data and the speed at which it does that.